# How to change properity of winform control by clicking on a button in ChromiumWebBrowser?

Tags: cefsharp

I try to change the text of label1 in winform by clicking on a button in ChromiumWebBrowser, but that text just didn't change.

the code of Form1.cs:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://localhost/pro/test.html")
   {
    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
    };
    this.panel1.Controls.Add(browser);
    browser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("callbackObj", new Form1());
}

public void changeText()
{
    this.InvokeOnUiThreadIfRequired(() => label1.Text = "show me the money");
}
```

the code of test.html :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var change = function () {
    callbackObj.changeText();
}
</script>
<button id="test-btn" onclick="change()">click me to change text of label1</button>
```

Comment: Avoid using your `Form` for binding as all methods and properties will be potentially exposed. Create an object and pass in a reference to your form (a simple proxy in effect).

Comment: thank you for your advice. I will improve my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you register the form object, you are making a new invisible form. Try passing "this" instead for the current visible instance.

I.e.,

```
browser.RegisterAsyncJsObject("callbackObj", this);
```